# $\int_{E_n} |g|^q = \left|\int_E \chi_{E_n}\cdot \text{sgn}(g)\cdot g \cdot |g|^{q-1}\cdot |g|\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand why the following equation is true.  Here $E$ is a measurable set and all functions are defined and measurable on it.  $1<p,q,<\infty$ such that $\frac 1 p+\frac 1 q=1$ and $g\in L^q(E)$.  $E_n= \{ x \in E:|g|\le n \}$.  And there exists a number $M$ such that for every $f\in L^p(E)$, we have $\left|\int_Efg\right|\le M
||f||_p$.

$$\int_{E_n} |g|^q = \left|\int_E \chi_{E_n}\cdot \text{sgn}(g)\cdot g \cdot |g|^{q-1}\cdot |g|\right|$$

My main problem with this is that it seems like the powers are off by one.  I would think that on $E_n$,

$$|g|^q = \chi_{E_n}\cdot |g|\cdot |g|^{q-1} = \chi_{E_n}\cdot\text{sgn}(g)\cdot g \cdot |g|^{q-1}$$

But even if we correct the extra factor of $|g|$ then I don't understand how we can write this as an equality.  If we're using the "integral triangle inequalty" or whatever $\left|\int_Ef\right|\le\int_E|f|$ is called, then shouldn't the equality actually be an inequality?  Is there some reason why in this particular setting we can actually have equality?

Comment: If everything is positive, we can put the absolut value inside or outside, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ah, I see, because we're not actually losing the absolute value inside, just putting an extra "redundant" pair around everything.  That makes sense.  And I'm not missing something dumb about the extra factor of $g$?  That is to say, I'm right about that being a little mistake?

Comment: Indeed, I think there is simply a $\vert g\vert$ too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last $|g|$ is wrong, maybe a typographical error or so. We have that $|g|^q=\operatorname{sign}(g)\cdot g\cdot |g|^{q-1}$ as $\operatorname{sign}(g)\cdot g=|g|$ and $|g|\cdot |g|^{q-1}=|g|^q$.

In general we define $\operatorname{sign}(g)$ as

$$
\operatorname{sign}(g):=\begin{cases}
\frac{g}{|g|},&\text{ when }|g|\neq 0\\
0,& \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$